# Importing SAS files into R from directories with special characters

Tags: r, encoding, import, special-characters

I am trying to import sas7bdat files into R using the `haven` package. The problem lies in the directory having special characters e.g.

`read_sas("Q:/Directory1/øøø/sasfile.sas7bdat")`

This returns an error message:

`Error in df_parse_sas_file(spec_data, spec_cat, encoding = encoding, catalog_encoding = catalog_encoding, : Failed to parse Q:/Directory1/øøø/sasfile.sas7bdat: Unable to open file.`.

The characters are Danish and I cannot change the file directory names.

Is there a way to solve for this issue?

Comment: What version of R are you using?  From GITHUB it looks like it was fixed in 3.5  https://github.com/tidyverse/haven/commit/52b11d16d438e9608b6ba4e6dcc21a978c97b188

Comment: @Tom My R version is 3.5.0 (2018-04-23). The link was committed in June of that year so might I perhaps be in need of an update?

Comment: An alternative (that I don't love) may be to set your working directory past the special characters and switch back after reading in the data.

Comment: @Andrew It unfortunately still tries to parse the entire directory name and returns the same error. I had the same idea, but no luck there!

Comment: Plenty of drawbacks to this solution but you may also be able to create a workflow using `file.copy()` to move, read, and then clean up. Of course, depending your permissions.

Comment: @Adzil I'm facing the same issue. It used to work before. Now, read_sas doesn't work for any file and I get the same error as you posted. Did you find the solution?